# How to push to multiple git remotes easily?

Tags: git

I have the same code deployed to multiple remotes (bitbucket and github) so I have to do this every time (which is fine):

`git add .; git commit -m "msg"; git push origin master; git push github master;`

But the real issue starts here.. First, bitbucket asks me for my token, I supply it, then github asks for both my username and token.. Is there an easier way to save these so I don't supply every time?

I prefer not to set a global git config email, I would rather use a fake email, but I'm OK with any solution, or additional software like a credential manager, or generating a common public key for all repos and somehow storing it and supplying automatically.

I also prefer a solution that doesn't require `ssh`, but it's OK if it is the only way :)

Thanks!

Comment: With ssh it's a piece of cake because you can install the same certificate on both hostings.... or even 2 different certificates and have them both _ssh-added_ so that there is no need to specify one or the other when pushing.

Comment: I'm using other remotes to deploy my node.js app so I'm not sure if they support SSH, but I would really appreciate if you can send an answer about how to do it :) Thanks

Comment: Why not set one as a mirror of the other and do the sync with a cron instead to push to several repo ?

Comment: @Ôrel I don't know how to do that either. But I would like to control what I push to which repo. I just want a way to skip supplying the tokens :)

Comment: I just found what I was looking for, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55472861/14051057 I flagged this question as a duplicate. Thanks for all the help!